# Why doesn't nested div width render as expected in webKit and Gecko?

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

Here is my code:

i am assuming am doing something wrong, but am expecting the padding on the right to also be 2px?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   div{border:solid 1px gray;}
   #outer{width:200px; padding:2px;}
   #inner{width:100%;}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="outer">
   <div id="inner">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Render:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have specified the size of the inner box to be the same size as the outer box. Set the width to auto and your problem goes away.

The padding makes an extra invisible box around your object, so the actual size of the outer is more than 200. However, inside it is 200. Same with the border. On the inner box, when you then specify it to be 100% it will be 200px, but the border will take up 2px, making an offset that makes it look like the padding is not being applied.

Comment: Thanks, you make sense, but setting the width to auto is exactly like not setting width.  Is the only way to solve this to specify the inner div's width to render correctly?

Comment: Yes. Basically. The major reason most people dont notice this problem is that if you have two boxes inside eachother with a border of 1, then it looks correct, but in fact on the right side, the outer most line belongs to the inner box. Places where they do consider this problem, it is common to set the size via js, where you can calc the correct width

Comment: @all , someone can explain me what is webkit and gecko , i always see these terms and even in css??

Comment: @gov, those are the display engine names used in the various browsers. Many different browsers may use the same engine.

Comment: like chrome, safari and konqueror use webkit while firefox, seamonkey, netscape are based on gecko

Answer (score 1):

div is a block level element, which by definition will expand to take up the full width of its parent container taking into account any margins, padding and borders.  specifying the #inner width to 100% is effectively the same as setting it to 200px.  Just remove the width declaration and you'll be all set.